# iOS/Android: Open numeric keyboard on password-type input field

Tags: angularjs, input, keyboard, passwords, numeric

In my Angular/Ionic app there is a PIN number security, where the user needs to enter 3 digits in three different input fields.

I use inputs of "password" type for that, but I'd like to show a telephone-type keyboard (with only the 10 digits) when the user taps on those inputs.

Using `<input type="tel">` is not good because I want the inputs to hide the digits like password-type inputs.

Any idea on how to do this? Also, this needs to work on both Android/iOS platforms.

Cheers,

tomatoKetchup

Comment: pls refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871929/how-to-make-input-field-type-both-numeric-and-password

Answer (score 6):

Using css you can do this

Add this class to your css.

```
.mask-text {
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
    -moz-webkit-text-security: disc;
    -moz-text-security: disc;
}
```

And use it in your input element, it will work in IOS 6 + and android 4.0 +     devices. It does not work with Windows devices.

```
<input class="form-control mask-text" type="tel"
    name="account"  ng-    model="my.model" >'
```

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not
> use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every
> use

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-security