# Show numeric keyboard on mobile in password input type

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular5

I want to make

```
<input type="password">
```

to display numeric keyboard only on mobile devices (iOS/Android).

## I have seen solutions like:

```
input[type=number] {
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

***But*** I cannot use this because of security and accessibility. Input value will be visible in inspector and voice over reads the numbers out loud.

Is there a way to achieve hidden input with numeric keyboard and proper accessibility?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178556/phone-numeric-keyboard-for-text-input

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126856/make-input-type-password-use-number-pad-on-mobile-devices

Comment: @Muath I need the input type to be password so that the input is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Try this... `<input type="password" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">`

**Updated Answer:**

Put a couple more minutes of thought into this. I've got it (and tested).

```css
/* Requires discs as characters */
input[type="number"] { 
  -webkit-text-security: disc !important; 
}

/* Removes Spin Button */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <label for="pin" class="my-1 mr-2 strong">Password</label>
  <input class="form-control pin" id="pin" type="number" inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="off"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you use IE on a mobile device?

Comment: inputmode attribute should prevent non numeric in all browsers, that didnt work. Sorry for not specifying earlier.